# How do I find record above and below based on rank

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `scoreboard` and I want to fetch two player above and below based on rank for the arbitrary player.

For example, The given table contains the name and rating.

| name | rating |
| --- | --- |
| Captain | 2100 |
| Ninja | 1300 |
| Mango | 1760 |
| Steve | 1100 |
| Benny | 899 |
| Zeus | 800 |
| Zeprus | 1200 |

For a given player Zephrus, I need to show below records. Two above him and two below.

| rank | name | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Mango | 1760 |
| 3 | Ninja | 1300 |
| 4 | Zeprus | 1200 |
| 5 | Steve | 1100 |
| 6 | Benny | 899 |

How can I achieve this? I got to know how to find rank using the rank window function in PostgreSQL but not sure how do I achieve two above and two below for a given player effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rank` window function and select the rows with rank within 2 places from the `name` you're looking for:

```
with u as
(select *, rank() over(order by rating desc) as r from scoreboard),
v as 
(select r from u where name ='Zeprus')
(select r, name, rating from u where abs(r - (select r from v)) <= 2 order by r)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=51c4afecaa24e677bad8d93c6c0bd629)